# Can I clone only the metadata/version tracking folder from github

Tags: git, github

My project is in many GBs. All I need is `git log` . Ideally it should suffice for me if I can just fetch the `.git` folder which tracks the versions.

Comment: That is exactly what is copied when you fetch from or clone a repo.

Comment: then where does the contents of files come from ?

Comment: From checking out master or whatever branch is checked out. Then the tree associated with the version you are checking out is expanded (from the DB of objects that was fetched) into your working tree

Comment: I don't need to check out `master or whatever branch`

Comment: Let alone unchanged files, I don't even need the information found in `git diff`, I just need `git log` for which contents of file are not needed. I dont need any information inside any files whatsoever.

Comment: Hey, no spamming.... you asked a question, I'm giving you the answer, even to the point of explaining where all the files came from when you check out. I _guess_ (not sure, but I guess it's technically possible by using `git fetch some-remote object-id` perhaps with an option to ask to only fetch that object and not continue recursively) that you could ask to fetch a single revision object (the tip of a branch, say), analyze its parents and then continue pulling revision objects recursively. That way you might avoid pulling file/tree information.

Comment: ... not sure if by pulling all those revisions objects you will be able to use git log, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `git clone --bare <repo>`

Comment: Yes, but it's important to note that the `.git/` folder isn't just metadata—it also contains the repository's full history. Every version of every file. If the repository is many gigabytes the `.git/` folder probably is too.

Comment: but the size being cloned is still the same (in many GBs for my case)

Comment: @ishandutta2007, the problem is that you've asked two different questions. "Only the metadata" and "the version tracking folder" are different things. ack_inc has answered the second part correctly. I think your core misunderstanding is to think that you can do `git log` without having a copy of the repository. You can't.

Comment: @Chris: Yes that's my understanding, It would be great if you can elaborate and help me understand.

Comment: @ishandutta2007, I'm not sure what more there is to say. The `.git/` directory contains the entire history of a repository, not just metadata. It can be used to hydrate a working copy from any commit, branch, or tag that exists in the repo. It therefore must necessarily contain the contents of every committed version of every file. There is no way to just clone metadata. The accepted answer on the duplicate question talks about `ls-remote`, but I don't think that helps you. I think you'll just have to put up with the size of the repo.